# How to select array from Highchart.series?

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/ErzQs/

How can I get the output from series0 ? I need the datapoints ... but my solution does not work properly.

```
data = chart.series[0].data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the data this way:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    data = chart.series[0].data;
    $(chart.series[0].data).each(function (index, element) {            
        alert(this.y);
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ErzQs/1/